# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\35508\Desktop\myfolder\myapp\node_modules\react-double-scrollbar\dist\DoubleScrollbar.js.map

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies

```html
//---> my table.js file
import React from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

const Table = () => {
  const data = [
    { name: "Praveen", age: 12 },
    { name: "Rahul", age: 12 },
    { name: "Suresh", age: 12 },
    { name: "Ramu", age: 15 },
  ];
  const columns = [
    { title: "Name", field: "name" },
    { title: "Age", field: "age" }
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <MaterialTable title="Material-Table" 
      data={data}
      columns={columns} />
    </>
  );
};
export default Table;
```

```html
//---> my index.js file 
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Table from './Table';
import "./index.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <Table/>
  </>
);
```

I'm trying to create a material-ui table using the default materail-ui table library. but it throws the above mentioned error. my node version is v18.13.0 and npm version is 8.19.3. I've run the commands

```
npm install react-double-scrollbar --save
```

I've tried adding the GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false before the start script in package.json, but it didn't work. I'm expecting the material-ui table component in my app on running

```
npm start
```

command.

Answer (score 0):

May you can add some more information:

1. What is the npm start command doing?
2. May a minimal code snippet where you import the table?

Comment: "npm start" is basically to run the application

Comment: Tried to use the Table directly in the index.js?

Comment: no, but why not in table.js?